Vampire/monster sleeps in underwater cellar, those turned sleep with their lungs on the outside
It should have come out before 1996 if I remember correctly.
In the beginning there are two female friends who walks around this abandoned cellar with water up to the knees. One of them gets dragged down by this vampire and the other one gets away.
Then there is this kid whose mother or grandmother is turned into a vampire, when she sleeps she has her lungs outside the body.
And there is a male who kinda "action hero-y" and comical relief if I remember correctly and the guy and the girl team up to fight the vampire hordes with a pickup truck that has some lights that damages the vampire.
That's all I remember, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sounds like Children of the Night with Karen Black from 1991:

In the quiet town of Allburg, USA, Lucy Barret (Ami Dolenz) and her grandmother Hillary Barret (Shirley Spiegler Jacobs) welcome Lucy's friend Cindy Thompson (Maya McLaughlin), who lives with her mother Karen Thompson (Karen Black) in River Junction and will spend a couple of days with Lucy. Cindy invites Lucy to go to swim in the crypt of the church on the Cherry Street, in River Junction, in a weird ritual. When the teenagers are swimming, an evil creature is revived and attacks Cindy.

The vampires there have their lungs outside their bodies and live in the water. Here's the trailer:



